# Access to path is denied c#

Tags: c#

I already search some of the topics here about access to path is denied but it's different from my problem.

I made a music player application for wp7 in vs studio. The music player is working fine if i debug it or deploy it in my Computer.

I burned the music player to cd using nero because i'm going to pass it to my professor but when debug or deploy it, it shows error.

Here's the error.

[image]

How can i burn my application to cd correctly??

Comment: Did you just burn a data disk of the source/  If so, when you compile it it is likely that Visual Studio is trying to WRITE to some of those files, and you cannot have random writes on a burned and closed DVD.  Either copy it from the disk and run it on the local harddrive, or use a flash drive.

Comment: Did you create an installer for the player? The packager will create a zip content which you need to deploy to the device

Comment: yes I burnt it as a data disk.

@abhishek how to create installer? will I be able to run it in my computer if I burn the installer to cd?

Comment: @MarcQuebrarTan Hey I have added an answer. I think you should copy the content to your hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you debugging through the CD? You can only debug through a writable CD as Visual Studio will need to write contents to the files located in the `obj` directory. This means that if it's a Read Only CD, then you won't be able to debug through the CD.

Thanks,

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok. So the only way is to copy the contents of cd to harddisk.

Comment: @MarcQuebrarTan Yep, because when burning files/directories to a CD, they take the attribute 'ReadOnly' which makes a specific file or directory write-protected. Copying the files or directories from the CD to the hard disk may fix the problem, make sure that you do not include the attribute while copying so it'd be writable once again. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot do that. Basically, the Windows Phone needs a simulator to run on your computer. The Visual studio deploys the executable to the [emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which runs on your pc.

But why do you require to ship your code ? The music player is intended to run on an actual device, isnt it ? To deploy it to an actual device, you need to package it and upload to windows store or if your device supports side-loading you can load it manually from the package created.

Other than that, if you want your entire source to run on your pc, it is recommended to copy to source code in hard disk and run it from there. Please make sure after you copy the folder, you right click on it and turn off the readonly attribute from the entire folder hierarchy.

I hope this will help you.